# Water softener unused for 11 months—safe to use?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

We just bought a new house, which has a salt-based water softener (picture below). The sellers hadn't been living in the house since last December (2022) while they were having it remodeled, so they turned off the softener and bypassed it via valves. Altogether, it has been bypassed/off for 11 months.

After we bought the house, the seller told us that, to use the softener, we simply need to un-bypass the softener and run the regeneration cycle to "flush" it through.

Is that actually all that needs to be done? Is there any issue with it having sat unused for such a long time?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Culligan recommends sanitizing the water softener if it has sat unused for a week or more. This applies to their High Efficiency models from 2011 onward. Excerpt from the installation and maintenance manual:

[image: e]

To determine how many cubic feet of resin are in your softener tank, you can use this reference from aquatel.ca

[image]